# Vector in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

How I can iterate a vector in a JSP page?

I have done it:

```
<%
 Vector value = (Vector) request.getAttribute("status");
 for (Enumeration e = value.elements(); e.hasMoreElements(); )
 {
        StatusItem myStatus = (StatusItem) e.nextElement();

 }
%>
```

Is there any way to do it with jsp tags?
Thx

Comment: `Vector` is a legacy Java class. It was over a decade ago succeeded by the improved `ArrayList`. I'd suggest to keep your code up to date and ignore tutorials which are over 10 years old.

Comment: that i know it, but I'm working with a system that only supports JDK1.1

Comment: Then it shouldn't support JSPs.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print out the contents of the vector like this:

```
<c:foreach var="myStatus" items="${status}" >
  <!-- print out the value of each status in the vector.
       Method getValue() must exist in the status class.-->
  <c:out value="${myStatus.value}"/>
</c:foreach>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate collections by [`<c:forEach>`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) jstl tag:

```
<c:forEach var="s" items="${status}">
    item is: ${s}
</c:forEach>
```